# etcd cannot start - vendor preset: disabled

Tags: azure, vagrant, coreos

Use this cloud-config to start start coreos using vagrant:

```
#cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd2:
    name: core-01
    initial-advertise-peer-urls: http://$private_ipv4:2380
    listen-peer-urls:
    http://$private_ipv4:2380,http://$private_ipv4:7001
    initial-cluster-token: core-01_etcd
    initial-cluster: core-01=http://$private_ipv4:2380
    initial-cluster-state: new
    advertise-client-urls:
    http://$public_ipv4:2379,http://$public_ipv4:4001
    listen-client-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001
  fleet:
    public-ip: $public_ipv4
  flannel:
    interface: $public_ipv4
  units:
    - name: etcd2.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
    - name: flanneld.service
      drop-ins:
      - name: 50-network-config.conf
        content: |
          [Service]
          ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{ "Network": "10.1.0.0/16" }'
      command: start
    - name: docker-tcp.socket
      command: start
      enable: true
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Docker Socket for the API

        [Socket]
        ListenStream=2375
        Service=docker.service
        BindIPv6Only=both

        [Install]
        WantedBy=sockets.target
```

The etcd cannot start:

```
systemctl status etcd
● etcd.service - etcd
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib64/systemd/system/etcd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I start a CoreOS VM on Azure without cloud-config, it give me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for the service start mode:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep etcd
```

it should be enabled.

If it is "masked"

```
systemctl unmask etcd.service
```

If it is "disabled"

```
systemctl enable etcd.service
```

In the cloud-config file we see that more Services are needed.
So you can use

```
systemctl edit etcd.service --full
```

And edit this service-file:

```
[Unit]
#Description=etcd...
#...
#After=network.target
#e.g. Start this Service before etcd.service
Wants=flanneld.service
```

For a more detailed systemctl description see on:

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd
```